# Rx.NET "gate" operator

Tags: c#, system.reactive

[Note: I am using 3.1 if that matters. Also, I've asked this on codereview but no responses so far.]

I need an operator to allow a stream of booleans to act as a gate for another stream (let values pass when the gate stream is true, drop them when it's false). I would normally use Switch for this, but if the source stream is cold it will keep recreating it, which I don't want.

I also want to clean up after myself, so that the result completes if either of the source or the gate complete.

```
public static IObservable<T> When<T>(this IObservable<T> source, IObservable<bool> gate)
{
    var s = source.Publish().RefCount();
    var g = gate.Publish().RefCount();

    var sourceCompleted = s.TakeLast(1).DefaultIfEmpty().Select(_ => Unit.Default);
    var gateCompleted = g.TakeLast(1).DefaultIfEmpty().Select(_ => Unit.Default);

    var anyCompleted = Observable.Amb(sourceCompleted, gateCompleted);

    var flag = false;
    g.TakeUntil(anyCompleted).Subscribe(value => flag = value);

    return s.Where(_ => flag).TakeUntil(anyCompleted);
}
```

Besides the overall verbosity, I dislike that I subscribe to the gate even if the result is never subscribed to (in which case this operator should be a no-op). Is there a way to get rid of that subscribe?

I have also tried this implementation, but it's even worse when it comes to cleaning up after itself:

```
return Observable.Create<T>(
    o =>
    {
        var flag = false;
        gate.Subscribe(value => flag = value);

        return source.Subscribe(
            value =>
            {
                if (flag) o.OnNext(value);
            });
    });
```

These are the tests I'm using to check the implementation:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    var output = new List<int>();

    var source = new Subject<int>();
    var gate = new Subject<bool>();

    var result = source.When(gate);
    result.Subscribe(output.Add, () => output.Add(-1));

    // the gate starts with false, so the source events are ignored
    source.OnNext(1);
    source.OnNext(2);
    source.OnNext(3);
    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(new int[0], output);

    // setting the gate to true will let the source events pass
    gate.OnNext(true);
    source.OnNext(4);
    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(new[] { 4 }, output);
    source.OnNext(5);
    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(new[] { 4, 5 }, output);

    // setting the gate to false stops source events from propagating again
    gate.OnNext(false);
    source.OnNext(6);
    source.OnNext(7);
    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(new[] { 4, 5 }, output);

    // completing the source also completes the result
    source.OnCompleted();
    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(new[] { 4, 5, -1 }, output);
}

[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod2()
{
    // completing the gate also completes the result
    var output = new List<int>();

    var source = new Subject<int>();
    var gate = new Subject<bool>();

    var result = source.When(gate);
    result.Subscribe(output.Add, () => output.Add(-1));

    gate.OnCompleted();
    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(new[] { -1 }, output);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Update**: This terminates when gate terminates as well. I missed `TestMethod2` in the copy/paste:

```
    return gate.Publish(_gate => source
        .WithLatestFrom(_gate.StartWith(false), (value, b) => (value, b))
        .Where(t => t.b)
        .Select(t => t.value)
        .TakeUntil(_gate.IgnoreElements().Materialize()
    ));
```

---

This passes <strike>your tests</strike> `TestMethod1`, it doesn't terminate when the gate observable does.

```
public static IObservable<T> When<T>(this IObservable<T> source, IObservable<bool> gate)
{
    return source
        .WithLatestFrom(gate.StartWith(false), (value, b) => (value, b))
        .Where(t => t.b)
        .Select(t => t.value);
}
```

Comment: Thank you; this is very elegant (which I love) but it actually doesn't pass the second test (the result doesn't complete when the gate does). Are you seeing it pass?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see `TestMethod2`. Modified answer.

Comment: `WithLatestFrom` is already part of some versions of `System.Reactive`

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
public static IObservable<T> When<T>(this IObservable<T> source, IObservable<bool> gate)
{
    return
        source.Publish(ss => gate.Publish(gs =>
            gs
                .Select(g => g ? ss : ss.IgnoreElements())
                .Switch()
                .TakeUntil(Observable.Amb(
                    ss.Select(s => true).Materialize().LastAsync(),
                    gs.Materialize().LastAsync()))));
}
```

This passes both tests.

Comment: Another elegant response. How do you guys know all this stuff, I think I've been through two dozen Rx courses and there's a lot I still don't know :)

Comment: If you change the lambda inside the Publish to this, it works:

`var gg = gate.Publish().RefCount();
                    var bothCompleted = Observable.Amb(ss.WhenCompleted(), gg.WhenCompleted());

                    return gate.Select(g => g ? ss : ss.IgnoreElements()).Switch().TakeUntil(bothCompleted);`

where `WhenCompleted` is just

`.Select(_ => Unit.Default).IgnoreElements().Concat(Observable.Return(Unit.Default))`

Comment: @MarcelPopescu - Beware the `.Publish().RefCount()` - it creates fragile, run once, observables. They can easily make an observable that appears to run fine once fail the second time. It's generally better to encapsulate within a `.Publish(inner => { })`.

Comment: @MarcelPopescu - I took a variation of your query and got it working.

Comment: Thank you for the warning; I did have problems with `.Publish().RefCount()` before. I'll try to avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track with `Observable.Create`. You should call the onError and onCompleted from both subscriptions on the observable to properly complete or error it when needed. Also by returning both the `IDisposable`s within the `Create` delegate you make sure both subscriptions are properly cleaned up if you intend to dispose the When subscription before either `source` or `gate` completes.

```
    public static IObservable<T> When<T>(this IObservable<T> source, IObservable<bool> gate)
    {
        return Observable.Create<T>(
            o =>
            {
                var flag = false;
                var gs = gate.Subscribe(
                    value => flag = value,
                    e => o.OnError(e),
                    () => o.OnCompleted());

                var ss = source.Subscribe(
                    value =>
                    {
                        if (flag) o.OnNext(value);
                    },
                    e => o.OnError(e), 
                    () => o.OnCompleted());

                return new CompositeDisposable(gs, ss);
            });
    }
```

A shorter, but much harder to read version using only Rx operators. For cold observables it probably needs a publish/refcount for the source.

```
    public static IObservable<T> When<T>(this IObservable<T> source, IObservable<bool> gate)
    {
        return gate
            .Select(g => g ? source : source.IgnoreElements())
            .Switch()
            .TakeUntil(source.Materialize()
                             .Where(s => s.Kind == NotificationKind.OnCompleted));
    }
```

Comment: Thank you; this is perfect.